# Authentication based on JWT token bearer fails under .NET Core 2.2 after move from 3.0

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I took a solution with a working authentication and downgraded it from Core 3.0 to Core 2.2. After that, the setup stopped working. Apparently, there's some minor difference in how it's organized that I'm missing. Comparing to the blogs and walk-throughs, I fail to see it.

The authentication is configured like this. Very simple, checking only the time stamp at the moment.

```
TokenValidationParameters parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
  ValidateLifetime = true,
  ValidateAudience = false,
  ValidateIssuer = false,
  ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:44385",
  ValidAudience = "https://localhost:44385"
};
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(config => config.TokenValidationParameters = parameters);
```

The token is issued using the following code.

```
TokenValidationParameters parameters = ...
byte[] secret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my_top_secret");
SecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret);
SigningCredentials credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

JwtSecurityToken jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
  "https://localhost:44385",
  "https://localhost:44385",
  { new Claim("a", "b") },
  DateTime.Now,
  DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3600),
  credentials
);

string token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
return Ok(new { token });
```

The returned value seems correct and I had it verified on JWT.IO so I don't suspect that to be the issue. However, when I paste that value into Postman (just like I did previously when everything worked), it gives me 401.

I don't know for sure what the problem is but I sense it has to do with the way I configured the authentication in the Startup class. My references I'm using for how it's supposed to look are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.2#jwt-bearer-authentication) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure).

What am I missing? Alternatively, how else could I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Given that Core 3.0 is in preview, will go GA in Sept, and 2.2 will be unsupported from Dec, why at all try something like that? ... waste of time if you ask me, as it all will be useless within a few months of time ... and do note, in 3.0 one need to opt-in for a lot of stuff that were included in 2.2, which might make it more to it than just the code you've showed here.

Comment: @LGSon Good point. The reason for it is that I started with Core 3 to poke around and get a sensation of the new stuff before GA comes out. Then, I discovered that lazy loading wasn't working - the method was there but burped out an error message about something internal not being implemented. Since I suddenly learned that I need to deliver the POC, I landed in the position where I had to downgrade and make it work. Also, I wasn't aware that GA was planned for September already. And that Core 2 goes unsupported, that's even more news to me. So this changes my situation nut that was the reason.

Comment: Do note, Core 2.2 goes unsupported... 2.1 does not, being on LTS https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md#net-core-21 ... https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md

Comment: @LGSon Oh, I see. I thought you meant that there's no LTS for Core 2 at all. This makes more sense. Still, kind of weird that they have Core 2.2, assumably an improvement from Core 2.1, and then choose to scratch the former keeping the latter.

Comment: They do the same for 3.0, where 3.1 will be LTS, and then from 5.0, every even will be LTS (6.0, 8.0,..., and increase main version yearly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @LGSon, I realized where the issue resided. For some weird and inexplicable reason, one has to specify `IssuerSigningKey` in the parameters. It makes sense if the value of `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` is set to `true` but in my case, I went by default, which is `false`.

```
TokenValidationParameters parameters = ...;
parameters.IssuerSigningKey = Configuration.GetSecurityKey();
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(config => config.TokenValidationParameters = parameters);
```

In Core 2.2 it's required to specify it regardless whether it's being used or not. In Core 3.0 (at least in the latest preview) it's not! This is a sneaky gotcha, in my opinion (borderline bug that's been corrected).

Comment: If this is using OpenID Connect you should not need to specify the isser key since one of the things an OpenID Connect certification checks is the key exchange via the discovery document.

Comment: @monty Is that confirmed by actual code? The reason for me asking is that *should not need* doesn't necessarily excludes *but you need anyway* in reality. As I mentioned - I've turned off validation for security key by setting the corresponding parameter to false. It's still required, despite that. It doesn't matter if it's an actually valid one or just a spoof I've make up. It needs to be specified, apparently. Or I might be missing something else. How do I confirm that I'm using OIDC as you mentioned?

Comment: if that confirmed by actual code? I have an application with multiple apis running and never configured the issuer key. I have no explicit demo by hand but we could create one on Github for figuring out. (hopefully I find the time to play around). One way to figure out if you are using OIDC is trying to open the openid configuration via [your-authority-url]/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: @monty Ohm that's what I get when I build based on Identity Server. That's when I get the *well-known*. But in this particular case, I'm not suing IDS.

Comment: if you are using this this nuget you probably use openid connect (also that the openid connect spec specifies the sub claim as mandatory within the token if it isn't a reference token) but still just guessing https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/